# Geektool internet on/of image

Tags: image, macos, connection, status, geektool

Trying to display an image when I am connected to the internet and another when I am not, I managed to come up with this 2 geeklet system:

1 shell:

```
if curl -f -s http://google.com > /dev/null ; then cp      /Users/mike/Documents/net.png /tmp/connstatus.png ; /Users/mike/Documents/noNet.png /tmp/connstatus.png ; fi ;
```

2 Image: 
`pointing to /tmp/connstatus.png`

It does not work.
Thanks in andvace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `else` statement in your `if`:

```
if curl -f -s http://google.com > /dev/null
then 
  cp /Users/mike/Documents/net.png /tmp/connstatus.png
else
  cp /Users/mike/Documents/noNet.png /tmp/connstatus.png
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input but it does not seem to work, no image displays

Comment: Once again, thanks for the help, yes it does you were right, the image changes, its just the path on the second geeklet thats glitchy, im pointing it to /private/tmp/connstatus.png, but the image on the desktop doesn't show

Comment: `/private/tmp` is not the same as `/tmp`, they are different paths.

Comment: Yes instead of typing the path to it i just used the wizard to get there, works perfectly, thanks!